# tag_id link for current country

Tags: wordpress

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying taxonomy pages for country
 *
 * 
 *
 *
 * @package toursgid
 */
 get_header(); ?>
 
  
 <h1><?php single_term_title('Страна: '); ?>.</h1>

 
<h1>CUISINE</h1>
<?php
global $wp_query;
$query = new WP_Query(
 array_merge(
  array(
   'post_type' => 'countries',
     'tour-type'    => 'spa'
  ), // это параметр который добавили мы
  $wp_query->query // это массив базового запроса текущей страницы
 )
);
  
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(8); ?>">tag CUISINE only for this country</a> <!-- ПРИ этой ссылки выводит всю кухню стран как реализовать для текущей страны ? -->
<?php
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 
 
<h1>NATURE</h1>

<?php
global $wp_query;
$query = new WP_Query(
 array_merge(
  array(
  'post_type' => 'countries',
     'tour-type'    => 'nature'
  ), // это параметр который добавили мы
  $wp_query->query // это массив базового запроса текущей страницы
 )
);
  
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    

 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(7); ?>">tag NATURE only for this country</a> <!-- ПРИ этой ссылки выводит всю природу стран как реализовать для текущей страны ?  -->

<?php
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    
<?php
get_footer();
```

Как сделать ссылку природа, или кухня для текущей страны. При таком выводе выводит все посты всех стран.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как они у вас связаны со страной?

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв.
costom post type => countries в нем в таксономии
1-country (france, russia,germany, и т.д)
2-tour-type (природа, кухня,достопримечательности, и т.д)
Создал страницу taxonomy-country.php в нем и выводится при клике на любую страну по флагу

Comment: Выше указанный код, является кодом для страницы taxonomy-country.php. В коде прописываю только цикл для вывода tour-type, а страница понимает на какой стране мы находимся из за   array_merge(
  array(
так как этот используется  при получении записей для текущей страницы, или архивов.

Comment: Страны вы используете как категории (таксономии), а туры как теги? И у каждого поста указана категория (страна) и тег (тур)? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: нет туры тоже как категории(таксономии)

Comment: Добавил screenshort посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: просто в коде get_tag_link(8); выводит как раз terms(термы) tour-type

Comment: Выводит ссылку на текущую страну но не на страну с термом nature

Comment: eugene_v 
Посмотрите пожалуйста на новый screenshort там где ссылка выводит все посты данной категории (природа) для всех стран, но мне надо чтобы вывел посты категории (природа) для текущей страны.

Comment: У меня сейчас получается при клике на ссылку посмотреть больше постов данной категории выводит все посты связанные со всеми странами

Comment: В шаблоне таксономии Страна нужно вывести все таксономии Туров, и под каждым из туров вы хотите получить посты? Я правильно понимаю эту структуру

Comment: Все верно НО под каждым из туров у меня получается выводить посты связанные с текущей страной. Я их вывожу по 4 записям мне нужно добавить ссылку или кнопку под каждым туром для вывода всех постов данного тура текущей страны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a href="toursgid.ru/?country=<?php echo get_query_var('taxonomy'); ?>&tour-type=nature" class="mob_bottom"> Природа (текущей страны) </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такую структуру:

```
         <ul>
            <?php $args = array(
                'post_type'     => 'countries',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby'      => 'name',
                'order'        => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'   => 1,
                'taxonomy'     => 'tour-type'
            );

            $categories = get_categories($args);
            if( $categories ){

                foreach( $categories as $cat ){ ?>

                        <p>Slug: <?php echo $cat->slug; ?></p>
                        <p>Name: <?php echo $cat->name; ?></p>

                        <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url') . '/tour-type/' . $cat->slug . '/' ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>

                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую.

Comment: 404 ошибка при переходе по ссылке

Comment: Обновил. Вот думаю вместо bloginfo('url') лучше что-то другое подкинуть, но для теста пока так. Проверьте что правильно указан слаги Таксономий

Comment: Спасибо за советы попробую сейчас

Comment: Не получается ваш код выводит только 
1-терм nature и все
2-при переходе по ссылке выдает ошибку 404

Comment: Возможно Spa без постов, `'hide_empty' => 1` скрывает пустые термы, а их и незачем выводить, если там пусто. А есть ссылка на сайт? Вы же понимаете, что по картинкам не так-то просто вам помочь

Comment: во всех категориях есть посты +4

Comment: На другом форуме мне дали ответ можете посмотреть и оценить
Во-первых, использовать фильтр pre_get_posts для вместо глобальный скоуп.
Во-вторых, чтобы ссылка на один термин одной таксономии учитывала другой термин другой таксономии, вам нужно или комбинировать их в урл (привет, custom rewrite rules, ну или на крайняк добавлять GET-параметром), либо сохранять выбранный термин из таксономии "страна" между страницами - например в куках. По другому WP совершенно никак не может догадаться о том, что при выборке по taxonomy=XXX&term_id=7 должно еще применяться AND taxonomy=YYY&term_id=Z

Comment: Обновил код, уберите там проверку `if($cat != $categories[0]) {` и закрывающий `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Добавите ниже свой вариант ответа, если все получится

Comment: Попробовал ваш новый код все ок но выводит опять же все посты стран в ссылке

Comment: Наконец то подсказали как надо пользователь KAGG Design дал ответ
<a  href="http://toursgid.ru/?country=<?php echo get_query_var('taxonomy'); ?>&tour-type=nature" class="mob_bottom">
    Природа (текущей страны)
</a>

Comment: Создаете ответ и переносите туда правильный вариант решения